# Swift - Stop speech recognition on no talk

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition

I am working on an app that uses the new Speech framework in ios 10 to do some speech-to-text stuff. What is the best way of stopping the recognition when the user stops talking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best but a possible solution is to track the elpsed time since last result and after a certain amount of time stop recognition.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: This is the best answer I could find.

Comment: I hope to find another solution but for now this works.